# Как объяснить непонимающим?

Tags: семантика

"Часть речи" это может быть группой слов? Речь это много слов, а часть это какая ее часть?

Comment: Возьмем слова "плавал,плаваю, буду плавать" и "летал,летаю, буду летать". Видим что они подчинены одинаковым законам. Объединив их в группу частей речи затем можно выписать эти законы и назвать это теорией речи,  грамматикой.

Answer (score 1):

```
        "Часть речи"- это может быть группой слов?
```

**Может.**

**Термин** “часть речи” объединяет в себе **совокупность слов**, имеющих одинаковые характеристики с точки зрения синтаксиса и морфологии. Каждый класс слов определяется наличием единого (в пределах группы) признака выбранной категории. В ходе построения предложений каждое слово определенного раздела выполняет свои грамматические задачи. https://sovetclub.ru/chto-takoe-chast-rechi

Бывают самостоятельные части речи (группы речи) и служебные.

1. Имена существительные - это представители  группы, характеризующие одушевленный или неодушевленный объект. Для их распознавания используются вопросы “Кто?” и “Что?”. Морфологическими категориями представителей данного класса выступают род, падеж и число. В составе предложения наиболее часто словам данного отделения отводится роль подлежащего, но может и выступать как дополнение.

Это сведения о целой группе слов. А если мы говорим об отдельном слове, то говорим, что это слово является существительным, частью речи, но имеем в виду, что оно относится к группе слов, которые объединяют общие признаки - постоянные и непостоянные.